# Issue while master is trying to read few registers via modbus serial console using python in raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pymodbus3, pymodbus

I am using RasPi connected to other system via serial console. My other system is running modbus master and Raspi is acting as modbus slave. Raspi has written to some register values and master is continuously asking for some register values.

Below is the code for slave

```
from pymodbus.server.sync import StartSerialServer

from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

from threading import Thread

from pandas import read_csv
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger("pymodbus")
#log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class test:
    # '''
    # '''
    def __init__(self, configfile='map_default.csv', timeoutval = .05, baudrateval=115200 ):
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        # initialize data store
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------#

        log.info("Initializing MODBUS simulator data store...")
        block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*2000)
        self.cphm_sim = ModbusSlaveContext()
        self.context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=self.cphm_sim, single=True)
        self.identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
        self.setIdentity( {"VendorName" : "inc",
                           "ProductCode" : Sim",
                           "VendorUrl" : "url.com/",
                           "ProductName" : "Simulator",
                           "ModelName" : "Simulator",
                           "MajorMinorRevision" : "1.0"})

        self.readConfig_init(configfile)

        thread = Thread(target=self.start_server, args=(timeoutval, baudrateval))
        thread.start()

    def start_server(self, timeoutval, baudrateval):
        log.error("Modbus Serial server started.Simulator data store initialization finished.")
        StartSerialServer(self.context, framer=ModbusRtuFramer, identity=self.identity, port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=timeoutval, baudrate=baudrateval)
```

Getting logs on Raspi as

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Error: Socket error occurred device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Getting Frame - 0x3 0x5 0x3a 0x0 0x2
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Request[3]
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame advanced, resetting header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.datastore.context:validate[3] 1339:2
DEBUG:pymodbus.datastore.context:getValues[3] 1339:2
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:send: 01030400000000fa33
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.server.sync:Error: Socket error occurred device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

On Master it is failed to retreive some of the registers. Sometimes It is able to read the registers and next time it reads successfully.

Anybody aware what wrong I am doing here

Comment: what version of pymodbus are you using ?Are you trying to read registers from multiple threads or from multiple clients? That seems to be the case here. Please share your master code as well.

Comment: Pymodbus version is 1.5. I am trying to read registers from single thread and single client. I don't have modbus master code but it is opening a sngle socket and just reading and writing on the registers values

Comment: What is the timeout and baudrate you are supplying ? start with lower baudrate and bigger timeouts (1 sec) and Use similar timeout in your master as well (same or greater than slave timeout). BTW, your code seems to be incomplete and Is there a reason why you want to run the server in a thread ?

Comment: There is no reason for running a server in a thread. I can change that but will it have any impact ?

Comment: If I dont run a thread, will it keep running? I want serial server to run continously

Comment: `StartSerialServer` is blocking and will run till you explicitly kill the process. If there is nothing you are doing after starting the server, you need not have to use threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171525/discussion-between-sanju-and-nitesh).